# curves inside-out

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

[image]

It does not bend the other way around, how do I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean the normals? You can change this by Flipping them (Alt-N, Flip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode with your object selected, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals, and check the *Inside* option.
[image]

Or, as Derrick commented, enter edit mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, then select *Flip* from the drop-down menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Problem resolved. :D